# Experience Editor Ribbon failing in preview mode because of breadcrumb

Tags: experience-editor

On some items, when opening preview mode in experience editor, the Ribbon breaks and a loader is displayed infinitely. The following message is logged:

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/Speak/Ribbon/Controls/BreadCrumb/Breadcrumb.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').

Source: Sitecore.Mvc
at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
at (Object , Object )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args)
at (Object , Object )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.RenderPlaceholderCore(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName)
at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.PageEditbar.PageEditBar.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
at Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render()
at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.PageEditbar.ControlsExtension.PageEditBar(Controls controls, Rendering rendering, HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper)
at ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Sitecore_ExperienceEditor_PageEditbar_PageEditBar_cshtml.Execute() in <my-webroot>\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\ExperienceEditor\PageEditbar\PageEditBar.cshtml:line 4
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that the reason for this was a publish restriction for the "en" language version on one of the parent items.

[image: Publish restriction causing issue]

```
- parent: publish restriction on en
-- child 1 ==> preview breaks on all languages
```

Removing the "en" version instead of setting a publish restriction fixed the issue. We've reported this as bug to Sitecore Support.